# Python holding onto a matplotlib plot to pass in several functions before showing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

What I am trying to do is to "initialise" a plot, and pass in datasets via a function to plot onto this graph. Then when I am happy the plot contains everything I want to show, I show it. How could I do this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_polynomials(solutions, train_x, train_y):
    x = np.arange(-5, 6)
    plt.plot(x, genPoly(x, solutions))
    plt.show()

data = read_coords("data.csv")
data = np.asarray(data)
system,solution = pol_regression(data[:,0], data[:,1], 2)
plot_polynomials(solution, data[:,0], data[:,1])

#I want to do something like this but im not sure what plot_polynomials() should contain
#to be able to "hold onto" the constructed graph before showing.
#I need all polynomials on the same graph
for i in range(11):
    system,solution = pol_regression(data[:,0], data[:,1], i)
    plot_polynomials(solution, data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

Comment: Remove `plt.show()` because that will show the plot. Put it at the position in your code where you want to show the plot.

Comment: What libraries do you use? Can you show us your imports, also can you provide some of the data so we can have a look?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, I must have messed up something else when I tried that. Works now:)

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you mean 'hold onto', but if you want to plot everything on one graph here is what you should do:

1. If you want to stack all your regression lines:

   ```
   plt.figure()
   for i in range(11):
       system,solution = pol_regression(data[:,0], data[:,1], i)
       x = np.arange(-5, 6)
       plt.plot(x, genPoly(x, solutions))

   plt.show()
   ```
2. if you want your plots, 11 of them on one figure (11 small figures):

   ```
   for i in range(11):
       system,solution = pol_regression(data[:,0], data[:,1], i)
       plt.subplot(11, 1, i) # 11 rows, 1 column, ith graph
       x = np.arange(-5, 6)
       plt.plot(x, genPoly(x, solutions))
   plt.show()
   ```

Hope this helps.